# React Router - passing props to route component from Link or programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass some custom properties to a component that React Router renders. I want the component to be unaware of React Router, if possible.

```
<Route path='/item' render={(props) => <MyComponent {...props} myParam={myParamValue}/>}/>
```

and in MyComponent

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { myParam } = this.props;
}
```

Is it possible to do so and if it is, can I do it dynamically? E.g.

```
<a href="/item" myParam={12345}>BLAH</a>
```

I know I can do this through history/location, but as I said, I'd prefer to keep my component unaware of router. My current workaround would be to have a wrapping container which takes the parameter from history/location and passes it to my component as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you investigate https://react-redux.js.org/ ?

It is very useful when you want to share application state across components

Comment: I have, yes. I'd prefer to have a component that is unaware of a redux store and react router if possible. I'd like to keep it as reusable as possible, providing necessary parameters only through props.